# How to create a R package using Rcpp under windows?

Tags: r, package, devtools

I've search a lot, but the tutorial I can find is all for simple R package. Even though I found a tutorial mentioning cpp document, it doesn't tell me details.

So can anyone tell me where to find a detailed tutorial?

Since I have used "devtools" and "roxygen2" to create a R package without using Rcpp, so I prefer a tutorial using "devtools" and "roxygen2". Thank you very much.

Comment: [advanced r - using Rcpp in a package](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html#rcpp-package)

Comment: I have seen it, but I think it's too simple. Do you know some more detailed tutorial?

Comment: I've not seen any other tutorials. In a package, if you go `usethis::use_rcpp()` it sets up all the required Rcpp skeleton code for you.

Comment: I then learnt by looking at other R packages which use Rcpp. My [`jsonify`](https://github.com/symbolixau/jsonify) library for example.

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html? Literally written by the original/main author of `devtools`, in a fantastic, lengthy, detailed tutorial about writing good R packages, including the use of `devtools::use_rcpp()`.